# Powershell: Regex matching with Get-content -Raw flag results in empty results

Tags: regex, powershell, match, powershell-5.1

***Solution was adding (?ms) to the front of my regex query***

I am trying to search for chunks of text within a file, and preserving the line breaks in a chunk.

When I define my variable as `$variable = get-content $fromfile`,
my function (below) is able to find the text I'm looking for but it is difficult to parse further due to a lack of line breaks

```
function FindBetween($first, $second, $importing){

    $pattern = "$first(.*?)$second"
    
    $result = [regex]::Match($importing, $pattern).Groups[1].Value

    return $result
}
```

when I define my variable as `$variable = get-content $fromfile -raw`, the output of my query is blank. I'm able to print the variable, and it does preserve the line breaks.

I run into the same issue regardless of if I add `\r\n` to the end of my pattern, if I use `@()` around my variable definition, if I use `-Delimiter \n`, or any combination of all those.

Whole code is here:

```
param($fromfile)

$working = get-content $fromfile -raw

function FindBetween($first, $second, $importing){

    $pattern = "(?ms)$first(.*?)$second"
    
    $result = [regex]::Match($importing, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
    #$result = select-string -InputObject $importing -Pattern $pattern

    return $result
}


FindBetween -first "host ####" -second "#### flag 2" -importing $working | Out-File "testresult.txt"
```

the file I'm testing it against looks like:

```
#### flag 1 host ####

stuff in between

#### flag 2 server ####

#### process manager ####
```

As to why I'm doing this:
I'm trying to automate taking a file that has defined sections with titles and outputting the content of those separate sections into a .csv (each section is formatted drastically different from each other). These files are all uniform to each other, containing the same sections and general content.

Comment: If you're doing `-raw` you probably need to change your RegEx to `"(?ms)$first(.*?)$second"` so that `.` will match new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing `-raw` you probably need to change your RegEx to `"(?ms)$first(.*?)$second"` so that `.` will match new lines.

Comment: Worth noting that it is `(?s)` that is crucial here (to make `.` match newlines too and therefore make `.*?` match _across lines_). You only need `(?m)` if you need `^` and `$` to match on _each line_.

Comment: Yes, excellent point. I never remember which one's which so I usually just include both of them. Thank you for the clarity!